# Django 1.4 'bool' object has no attribute 'rindex' , form Processing issue

Tags: python, django, token, python-2.6, django-1.4

Here it's my problem - http://dumpz.org/189956/
And it's my code, which makes this problem - http://dumpz.org/189954/
Why does it happens? How I can solve this one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW is supposed to point to the view you want to display when csrf token is missing or invalid.

From your setting I see you set that to False which is clearly not a view function.

If you want to skip the CSRF for a view you can use the decorator
eg.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt                                          
@csrf_exempt
def view(request):
...
```

Comment: @АлександрКривошеев glad that it helped, and remember to mark the answer if it is correct! ;)